# Splitting Data String in Data Extension into Separate Columns Based on Delimiter

Tags: query, dataextensions, ssjs, data-views

I have a data extension that contains the "Link Content" data from querying the _click data view. It returns rows of data with the url + the parameters we have in place. After the url, there is a "?" delimiter and then the parameters are separated by an underscore delimiter. For example, https://www.example.com??parameter1_parameter2_parameter3.html

I'm trying to modify this data so that the link and each parameter are separated into separate columns. For example -

URL | Parameter 1| Paremeter 2 | Parameter 3| 
https://www.example.com| Parameter 1 data | Parameter 2 data | Parameter 3 data |

This will be used for reporting, so I don't think the BuildRowSetFromString ampscript function is viable since this data will not be visualized in an email or landing page.